# Using pig to store data to Hbase

Tags: java, hbase, apache-pig

I have a table with schema

```
TOP: {businessid: bytearray,best_review::review_weight: double,best_review::REVIEWS_DATA::businessid: bytearray,best_review::REVIEWS_DATA::reviewid: bytearray,best_review::REVIEWS_DATA::stars: bytearray}
```

I want to store it in a Hbase table and I am using the following command

```
STORE TOP INTO 'hbase://master_data'USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
'master_info:best_review::review_weight, master_info:best_review::REVIEWS_DATA::reviewid, mastert_info:best_review::REVIEWS_DATA::stars ');
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:479)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:442)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:422)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:269)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.putNext(HBaseStorage.java:1003)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:136)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:558)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:477)
```

Please let me know how to run the storage command. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to HBaseStorage takes a list of colFamily:columns with space separated something like

> raw = LOAD 'hbase://SampleTable'
>          USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
>          'info:first_name info:last_name friends:* info:*')

Each column inside column list argument is space separated, and obviously two arguments are separated by comma.

I see you have :: at many places. Can you verify that

Comment: Yes i do have :: as I was trying to follow the schema. But even with using just : i get the exact same error. Basically some of the fields are coming from previous created table like "best_review::REVIEWS_DATA::businessid", the field 'businessid' was created in REVIEWS_DATA and subsequently carried over in the best_review to the current table TOP.

now when I try to store TOP I need to reference the businessid filed in the command HBaseStorage and have not been able to do that